# Singlestore partition on timestamp

Tags: singlestore

I have a table in SingleStore with ~10M of rows, each row representing a single event (with event name, user id, and event timestamp).
Most of my queries are filtered by the event timestamp, in other data-warehouses like BigQuery or Snowflake I would want to partition the table based on DATE(timestamp) - what is the equivalant in SingleStore?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since the timestamp is filtered on often, as long as it is high cardinality (to avoid data skew), then yes timestamp would make a good shard key in SingleStore. Please see the [docs](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/developer-resources/porting-tables-to-singlestoredb-cloud/choosing-a-shard-key.html) for more information about picking shard keys. Some supplemental [info](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/create-a-database/physical-database-schema-design/concepts-of-physical-database-schema-design/understanding-keys-and-indexes-in-singlestore.html)  about keys and indexes in SingleStore may also be helpful.